Depedency Injection with Autofac and Automapper
I have project where I implement Autofac and Automapper. There is no any problem when I added Automapper, but when I want to add mine implementation of interface I came across error with Automapper. My Global.asax.cs and AutoFacModule files:
Global.asax.cs
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Register your MVC controllers. (MvcApplication is the name of
            // the class in Global.asax.)
            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

            //Register AutoMapper here using AutoFacModule class (Both methods works)
            builder.RegisterModule<AutoFacModule>();

            // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
            var container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        }

AutoFacModule.cs
    public class AutoFacModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<AuthenticationModule>().As<IAuthenticationModule>();

            builder.Register(context => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                //Register Mapper Profile
                cfg.AddProfile<RepackagingOrdersModelsMapper>();
            }
            )).AsSelf().SingleInstance();

            builder.Register(c =>
            {
                //This resolves a new context that can be used later.
                var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
                var config = context.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>();
                return config.CreateMapper(context.Resolve);
            })
            .As<IMapper>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
    }

When I start the solution I got error like that:
System.IO.FileLoadException: “Unable to load file or set ‘AutoMapper, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005’ or one of its dependencies. The localized kit manifest definition does not match the kit reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)”
I got this error only when I add builder.RegisterType<AuthenticationModule>().As<IAuthenticationModule>(); into AutoFacModule.cs file. Without this line everything works fine. What's the other way to add this implementation?
I've tried to create separate file for mapper, but it didn't help.

https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#autofac
